# How to use CvInRange in Emgu CV

Tags: c#, emgucv

I am learning to use Emgu CV and stumbled upon this Open CV example : http://aishack.in/tutorials/tracking-colored-objects-in-opencv/

I want to recreate the `CvInRange` function in Emgu by creating this code :

```
// create upper & lower limit (HSV)
MCvScalar botLimit = new MCvScalar(20, 100, 100);
MCvScalar uprLimit = new MCvScalar(30, 255, 255);

// prepare the destination
Image<Hsv, byte> imageHSVDest = new Image<Hsv, byte>(imageWidth, imageHeight);

// 
CvInvoke.cvInRange(imageHSV, botLimit, uprLimit, imageHSVDest);
```

the `CvInvoke.cvInRange()` produce this error message (in vs2010) :

> Error  1   The best overloaded method match for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cvInRange(System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr)' has some invalid arguments
>       Error   2   Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Emgu.CV.Structure.MCvScalar' to 'System.IntPtr'
>       Error   3   Argument 3: cannot convert from 'Emgu.CV.Structure.MCvScalar' to 'System.IntPtr'

It seems there is a mismatch data type. I have searched how to convert Emgu `MCvScalar` to `IntPtr` to no avail.

I used the `MCvScalar` by translating OpenCV `cvScalar(20, 100, 100)` from the example. Is this wrong?

Comment: forgot to say that i have sucessfully do the basic things in my program like : open image, viewing the image in imagebox and convert it to HSV color space.

Answer (score 6):

I'm using Emgu CV 3.1.0. Stumbled upon a similar problem as you did and I solved it this way:

```
CvInvoke.InRange(imageHSV, new ScalarArray(new MCvScalar(20, 100, 100)), 
                           new ScalarArray(new MCvScalar(30, 255, 255)), imageHSVDest);
```

`MCvScalar` cannot be used directly in `CvInvoke.InRange` as the latter takes in `IInputArray` parameters, thus you have to wrap the scalars with the arrays.

---

Reference:
[CvInvoke.InRange Method Documentation](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/6577bad5-d270-efc5-a54f-0861f85c44fd.htm)

Answer (score 4):

Use the built-in Emgu CV function `InRange` instead. Then, it looks like this:

```
Hsv lowerLimit = new Hsv(20, 100, 100);
Hsv upperLimit = new Hsv(30, 255, 255);

Image<Gray, byte> imageHSVDest = imageHSV.InRange(lowerLimit, upperLimit);
```

Please observe that `imageHSVDest` is a binary image with values 0 (black) and 255 (white).